# Convert df value of specific columns to string if the digits of the df value in those columns is greater than or equal to 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to convert those values in a few columns to string if the number of digits of those numbers are greater than to equal to 12.

I am doing this so as to avoid scientific notation display when I write to excel of these numbers.

Code I tried :-

```
def count_digits(string):
 if string is None:
    return 0
 string=str(string)
 return sum(item.isdigit() for item in string)

if df['col1'].apply(count_digits) or df['col2'].apply(count_digits) or df['col3'].apply(count_digits) >= 12:
  df.values=str(df.values())
```

Sample `df` :-

```
Param  col1      col2         col3
A      56465780  56.678       None
B      19937000  430624000    26847651.79
D      4457000   999999999999 None
H      256000    344578000    None
K      225000    35           NaN
E      219000    NaN          None
```

Comment: "I am doing this so as to avoid scientific notation display when I write to excel of these numbers." -- Instead of trying a workaround, have you looked to see if there is a setting for this in excel?

Comment: On the Pandas side, you can do `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.20f}'.format` (or some number other than 20) to increase the number of decimals it will display.

Comment: I do not want all numbers to come as float unfortunately

Comment: I have updated my solution. Please let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly try:

```
def count_digits(string):
    if pd.isna(string):
        return ''
    elif (isinstance(string,(float,int))) or (string.isnumeric()):
        if len(str(string))>=12:
            return str(string)
        else:
            return string
    else:
        return string

Finally:
df.replace({'None':None,'nan':float('NaN')}).applymap(count_digits)
```

output:

```
  Param      col1                col2         col3
0     A  56465780  56.677999999999997             
1     B  19937000         430624000.0  26847651.79
2     D   4457000      999999999999.0             
3     H    256000         344578000.0             
4     K    225000                35.0             
5     E    219000
```

OR

If you don't want to count numbers after decimal `.` as the length then use:

```
def count_digits(string):
    if pd.isna(string):
        return ''
    elif (isinstance(string,(float,int))) or (string.isnumeric()):
        if len(str(string).split('.')[0])>=12:
            return str(string)
        else:
            return string
    else:
        return string
```

Comment: I tried this.It works in creating the digits >12 to string. However other columns are coming empty in the `df`. Is there any way to make this or apply this to only specific columns of the `df` with this logic? Also the alignment(left/right justify) of these cells has changed

Comment: @Scope can you provide the sample dataframe where it failed bcz I tested this function before posting answer

Comment: Refer to the sample df in the Post.  I would not say its failing, the other columns in the df are displaying empty

Comment: @Scope It is working fine on my side I tried.....btw made a little change in answer also added the output...kindly look **:)**

Comment: The `NaN` and `None` I want it to be displayed as empty.Let me try

Comment: @Scope so NaN and None remains same?...no change in them?

Comment: Thats right. `Nan`` and None` should be ""(empty) and display same way in excel and just the cells with >= 12 digits should be converted to string and appear same way. right now wherever empty im getting 0 and those converted to string coming as `99999999999999.0`

Comment: @Scope because if you convert float `99999999999999.0` to string then it will display like `99999999999999.0` but only datatype will change...btw updated answer for NaN...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: The old method worked. No the `99999999999999` are not float data type in `df`. Because of excel its being converted into scientific notation for which I thought of this method to display as string

Comment: @Scope it was coming like this `99999999999999.0` because of NaN present in your column

Comment: Pl. upvote the question if you think it could be helpful to  others  for the same purpose

Comment: @Scope sure sir..happy coding ***:)***

Answer (score 0):

```py
str_version = df.astype(str)
many_digits = str_version.apply(lambda s: s.str.count(r'\d') >= 12)
df[many_digits] = str_version
```

This creates a copy of the DataFrame where all values are strings, then creates a boolean DataFrame where values with more than 12 digits are represented as True, and then replaces values in the original DataFrame marked as True with the string version.

Comment: Im getting this error when I use your method `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of the DataFrame as text (no screenshots). Doing `print(df.head())` should suffice.

Comment: Ill try if I can. The issue dfs are  dynamically created which changes every iteration . I have float,int ,None types in my df.Thats the reason I wrote a function as mentioned in my post to count the digits